Absolute import doesn't work with redux folder
I've read this article and did as it said. Created jsconfig.json and made a 'src' absolute path.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

Now every folder in project can be imported absolutely without having a slash hell. But somehow the redux folder inside my src folder throws an error when imported absolutely.

Module not found: Error: Package path ./api/userApiSlice is not
exported from package C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\redux
(see exports field in
C:\web\1stprojectforserver\node_modules\redux\package.json)

I don't really understand what is happening here since the redux folder is inside src folder along all of the other folders that are used and imported into the project.
My suspicion is that absolute paths don't include subfolders and when you try to reach a subfolder of an absolute path, it throws an error. Is there a way to fix this?
Here are my imports:
import NavLinkStyled from "../UI/NavLinkStyled/NavLinkStyled";
import LegalMenu from "./LegalMenu";
import { useGetUserQuery } from "redux/api/userApiSlice";
import { useLogoutMutation } from "../../redux/api/authApiSlice";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import useAuth from "hooks/useAuth";
import { useState } from "react";
import { copyright } from "constants/constants";

hooks and constants are imported succesfully but redux (the one without ../../) throws an error.
Here's code for authApiSlice.js
import { apiSlice } from "./apiSlice";
const LOGIN = "login/";
const LOGOUT = "logout/";

export const authApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    login: builder.mutation({
      query: (credentials) => ({
        url: LOGIN,
        method: "POST",
        body: { ...credentials },
      }),
    }),
    logout: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: LOGOUT,
        method: "POST",
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(_, { queryFulfilled }) {
        await queryFulfilled;
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
        localStorage.removeItem("userId");
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useLoginMutation, useLogoutMutation } = authApiSlice;


add code for authApiSlice file

I've added the requested code

I replicated the directory structure on my machine. Absolute import works fine. I tried with create-react-app. Are you using vite or create-react-app?

I use create-react-app. As I understand it, there's some conflict with the redux itself. VSCode tries to import package from redux folder in node_modules. I tried excluding it from jsconfig but it still doesn't work.

Maybe try once with vite? Could be some issue with webpack

I will. But I really just want to get to the bottom of this.
